Data Type differences between Synapse Tables and Delta Lake Tables
I am looking for information around data type differences between Synapse Tables and Delta Lake Tables. Essentially, I want to know if Synapse Tables can be converted to Delta Lake Tables, without encountering any data type related issues.
Thanks in advance!

I mean Azure Synapse Analytics table. (can't edit my question)

I would start with the docs. What you're asking isn't a direct programming question, and there are non-trivial differences. Also, asking about converting tables is a different question altogether.

As you want to know if Synapse Tables can be converted to Delta Lake Tables Yes, you can convert Synapse tables to Delta Lake tables.
I have tried the below approach to get supported datatypes in Delta Lake & Synapse Dedicated pool.
In dedicated pool you try the below query to get info for datatypes:
SELECT
    name AS DataType,
    xtype AS TypeCode,
    length AS MaxLength,
    CASE
        WHEN xtype IN (99, 35, 167, 175, 231, 239) THEN 'Character String'
        WHEN xtype IN (48, 52, 56, 104, 106, 108, 122, 127) THEN 'Numeric'
        WHEN xtype IN (61, 58, 40) THEN 'Date and Time'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS DataTypeCategory
FROM
    sys.systypes
ORDER BY
    name;

Results:
DataType    TypeCode    MaxLength   DataTypeCategory
bigint  127 8   Numeric
binary  173 8000    Other
bit 104 1   Numeric
char    175 8000    Character String
date    40  3   Date and Time
datetime    61  8   Date and Time
datetime2   42  8   Other
datetimeoffset  43  10  Other
decimal 106 17  Numeric
float   62  8   Other
image   34  16  Other
int 56  4   Numeric
json    244 -1  Other
money   60  8   Other
nchar   239 8000    Character String
numeric 108 17  Numeric
nvarchar    231 8000    Character String
real    59  4   Other
smalldatetime   58  4   Date and Time
smallint    52  2   Numeric
smallmoney  122 4   Numeric
sql_variant 98  8016    Other
sysname 231 256 Character String
time    41  5   Other
tinyint 48  1   Numeric
uniqueidentifier    36  16  Other
varbinary   165 8000    Other
varchar 167 8000    Character String

To list all the data types that support Delta tables using PySpark:
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    ByteType, ShortType, IntegerType, LongType,
    FloatType, DoubleType, DecimalType,
    StringType, BinaryType, BooleanType,
    DateType, TimestampType, 
    ArrayType, MapType, StructType, StructField
)
delta_supported_data_types = [
    ByteType(), ShortType(), IntegerType(), LongType(),
    FloatType(), DoubleType(), DecimalType(),
    StringType(), BinaryType(), BooleanType(),
    DateType(), TimestampType(),
    ArrayType(StringType()),  
    MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()), 
    StructType([StructField("field1", StringType()), StructField("field2", IntegerType())])  
]
print("Supported data types for Delta tables in PySpark:")
for dtype in delta_supported_data_types:
    print(dtype.simpleString())

Supported data types for Delta tables in PySpark:
tinyint
smallint
int
bigint
float
double
decimal(10,0)
string
binary
boolean
date
timestamp
array<string>
map<string,int>
struct<field1:string,field2:int>

So Map your Synapse Data Types to Delta Lake Data Types accordingly.

This doesn't answer any question. This is, instead, some custom code that you wrote. The OP has not asked any programming question, and has not provided any code/data/behavior/errors at all. Please don't post answers to off-topic questions that are only soliciting information based on a requirement. Note: I even commented on the question, several days ago, that the OP should read the published docs to learn about the various services, differences, etc.

Hi @Dileep Raj Narayan Thumula, thanks a million, this helps.

@David Makogon, yes, this might not have been a programming question, but is still a question, how should one proceed if he has a Synapse Pool DB solution mart, that is desired to migrated to Delta Lake, and yes, I could not find any one single documentation stating data types, and this answer is pretty useful and handy.
